# How can I reinitialize an AngularJS directive in ng-repeat?

Tags: angularjs

This is my directive

```
app.directive('masonry', function() {
return function(scope, element, attrs) {
    scope.$watch(attrs.masonry,function(value){
        jQuery(function($) {
            var grid = $('.main_creation').masonry({
                itemSelector: '.creation',
                percentPosition: true,
                horizontalOrder: true
            });

            grid.imagesLoaded().progress( function() {
                grid.masonry('layout');
            });
        });
    });
};
```

});

This is my HTML

```
<div class="creation" ng-repeat="img in images" masonry>
  //some code
</div>
```

When first load the directive is functioning but if the ng-repeat is changing for example deleting or adding more data in ng-repeat the directive doesnt functioning.

EDIT:
Also I dont know why the watch doesnt trigger. When I console.log(attrs.masonry) their is changes.

Comment: Why you watch for `attrs.masonry` - it will never change. You can simple eliminate it and start function from `jQuery...`?

Comment: I'd suggest you to get a angular masonry library instead of writing your own.